# using the tmp folder on a apache

Tags: apache, tmp

I just pushed my website from my local development environment to my remote server and I've run into some problems. Specifically with the use of the /tmp folder. As a test I ran this

```
echo "the start";
$tmp = sys_get_temp_dir();
echo $tmp . "<br/>";
echo "the end."
```

The result is only:

"the start"

After that the script seems to die. But it gives me no error. (Can I do something in the apache config to show me errors??)

Anyway I first checked php.ini to see where the tmp directory is. No explicit folder is stated, so apache should be using the system default.

I then when to this file in /var/www/ to check the permissions. The permissions here are 777 so I don't think should have any trouble writing to the tmp folder.

And yet my problems persist. Any ideas??

Comment: have you tried using if ( !function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir')) { to see if it exists in your current setup?

Comment: So, it seem like you're right, the function does not exist. Does that mean I currently can't use the tmp folder on this system or just that this function does not exist.

Comment: this function only exists in php 5.2.1 and above maybe update your php (if possible) or find an alternative method to get tmp directory? what is your need to get the tmp directory? an alternative, but not recomended, is to create your own tmp directory and use that if you need an example let me know and i'll write an example in the answers. However if you are uploading files i think it would still result in the file been uploaded to your tmp location

Comment: Ok. I'm going to ask my host provider to update PHP. My remote system is currently 5.1.6. But theoretically, I should be able to save things to my tmp folder in 5.1.6 right? I use the tmp folder to save an xmlfile converted with xsl, and the loaded with simpleXML, so I can xpath info out of the converted xml document

Comment: you can still use your tmp folder but unless there is no alternative i wouldn't update php as some functions you use may be depreciated, and could break your code.

Comment: ok -- I think will update though, because my development system is 5.3, but my remote host is 5.1, so that difference could be part of my deployment problems